# Laravel 7 database host ignored?

Tags: laravel, docker

I currently have a setup of multiple env files which are loaded based on a domain.
Each has its own settings including the database.
The database host is shared. In this case 127.0.0.0 or localhost

I now decided to move to docker so now the host is "db" but it will not work. The issue seems to be that the host is ignored.

In my .env I have the following:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my-db
DB_USERNAME=my-db-user
DB_PASSWORD=my-db-password
```

In the file vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php there is this method:

```php
    protected function createPdoConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options)
    {
        if (class_exists(PDOConnection::class) && ! $this->isPersistentConnection($options)) {
            return new PDOConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
        }

        return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    }
```

Which I modified into this when trying to figure out what was going on:

```php
    protected function createPdoConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options)
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($dsn);
        var_dump($username);
        var_dump($password);
        var_dump($options);
        var_dump(env('DB_CONNECTION'));
        var_dump(env('DB_HOST'));
        var_dump(env('DB_PORT'));
        var_dump(env('DB_DATABASE'));
        var_dump(env('DB_USERNAME'));
        var_dump(env('DB_PASSWORD'));
        exit;
        if (class_exists(PDOConnection::class) && ! $this->isPersistentConnection($options)) {
            return new PDOConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
        }

        return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    }
```

Which results in this:

```html
string(54) "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=my-db"
string(11) "my-db-user"
string(32) "my-db-password"
array(5) {
  [8]=>
  int(0)
  [3]=>
  int(2)
  [11]=>
  int(0)
  [17]=>
  bool(false)
  [20]=>
  bool(false)
}
string(5) "mysql"
string(2) "db"
string(4) "3306"
string(7) "my-db"
string(7) "my-db-user"
string(64) "my-db-password"
```

Which shows that the environment file is being loaded, the correct variables are there yet the dns host is "host=127.0.0.1", now if I modify the file like this:

```php
    protected function createPdoConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options)
    {
        $dsn = str_replace('127.0.0.1', env('DB_HOST'), $dsn);
        if (class_exists(PDOConnection::class) && ! $this->isPersistentConnection($options)) {
            return new PDOConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
        }

        return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    }
```

The sites work so obviously laravel is either not taking the DB_HOST or is doing something to it, or is the combination of laravel PHP docker+mySQL docker?

Has anyone seen this behavior?

below my docker file

```
FROM local:php-7.2
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www-data
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www-data www-data
RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/www
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
USER www-data
RUN export DB_HOST=db
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `env` is not available in production mode. Did you add `.env` to your docker file? It is a hidden file so it may have skipped it while copying

Comment: The relevant setting is what is in config/database.php . NORMALLY this fills from .env, but if someone hardcoded '127.0.0.1' there (and removed the env()) call that would explain the behaviour.

Comment: @TobiasK. that is not the case, the value is not hardcoded.

Comment: @MaartenDev the issue was not the env, however your comment on env not being available in production mode is what helped me find the actual issue. It turns out I has not setting the environment APP_CONFIG_CACHE so all sites ended up sharing the same path, which had an old config file. Setting the proper APP_CONFIG_CACHE for each site solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

show your docker file.
You can try this:
**DB_HOST=docker_container_name**

Comment: I have added the docker file, and DB_HOST=docker_container_name, where docker_container_name for me is "db" did not work.

Comment: Where is your docker-compose.yml file?  Show me your db container file.